# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Code:

```
public static List<ExpressionListDictionary> GetAmounts()
{
    using (DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter())
    {
        LinqMetaData meta = new LinqMetaData(adapter);
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var endDate = now;
        var startDate = now.AddMonths(-3);

        var datas = ( from test in meta.Test
                      where test.DateCreated >= startDate && test.DateCreated <= endDate && test.ViaTo > 0 && test.Cancelled == 0 
                      select MonthOfYear(test.DateCreated)); // how can I get the month name correctly?              
    }  
}
```

`Cancelled` is `bool TestEntity.Cancelled`

I'm getting the error at the `where` statement. How can I fixed it?

Comment: What would `test.Cancelled = 0` normally mean in C#? (Not in SQL...)

Comment: Cancelled is bool TestEntity.Cancelled

Comment: Look carefully. What does `x = y` mean in C#? What operator is that?

Comment: Definetely not a comparison operator ...

Comment: Right. But you *want* a comparison, right? An equality comparison. So how would you perform an equality comparison in a normal C# `if` condition?

Comment: Considering your help and suggestions and also knowing that Cancelled is bool type, I add: renter.Cancelled == false and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, since `Cancelled` is a boolean property why you are trying to compare it with `0`? You can simply do this:-

```
 && test.Cancelled
```

Or  `&& !test.Cancelled` for negative case.

Answer (score 3):

Your  statement after last `&&` is not right you need `==` for comparing instead of `=`

`=` do assignment in C# that's why its complaining:

```
&& test.Cancelled == 0
```

### Update:

As `Cancelled` is `bool` you have to put `true` or `false` in comparison

Answer (score 1):

***You should correct this:***

```
&& test.Cancelled = 0
```

***Into the following:***

```
&& !test.Cancelled
```